# Querying hits per hour on Django timezone aware setup

Tags: python, mysql, django, datetime, timezone

I'm someone new at the whole Django thing and find myself stuck on the whole timezone awareness kerfuffle.

**Problem**

I would like to query the database to create a report such as:

```
Time of day | Clicks
--------------------
12 am       | 3
1 am        | 12
2 am        | 28
3 am        | 48
...
```

I would like these to be shown *based on the timezone of the user* that created the event, not in the timezone setting of the system.

**Current approach**

Given the following model (simplified to avoid clutter) and assuming proper libraries are imported.

```
class Event(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField()
    created = models.DateTimeField()
    user = models.CharField()
```

I then created the following in `tests.py`

```
def test_events_per_day(self):

# creates events in two timezones

    date = datetime(2017, 1, 13, 12, 0, 0, 0, pytz.timezone('Pacific/Auckland'))
    date2 = datetime(2017, 1, 13, 12, 0, 0, 0, pytz.timezone('UTC'))

    Event.objects.create(
        type='click',
        created=date.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:00.%f%z'),
        user = 'user 1'
    )

    Event.objects.create(
        type='click',
        created=date2.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:00.%f%z'),
        user = 'user 2'
    )

    event_per_day_count = Event.objects \
        .filter(type='click') \
        .annotate(day=TruncDay('created')) \
        .values('day') \
        .annotate(events=Count('user', distinct = True)) \
        .order_by('day')


    self.assertEquals(over_time.first().get('events'), 2)
    # FAIL: AssertionError: 1 != 2
    # PASS if I use the same date for both
```

When I look at the database and the Timezone info is gone and it all appears to be saved in UTC ([as the first line of the documentation states](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/timezones/)).

I had a look at normalization but I couldn't quite see how to fix it using that. Storying the timezone info in the database and convert as we go seems expensive. In my despair, I even tried setting `USE_TZ = False` to see what would happen and Django told me MySQL doesn't like that.

As mentioned, I'm still making a bit of sense of how this works, so any pointers, comments or words of encouragement would be welcome.

Comment: No. My problem is that I don't know how to retrieve all events for a particular hour while ignoring the timezone info. As I said, I want to see how many people created a click say, at 9am, but on the user timezone, not on the system timezone.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get what you want by specifying [the tzinfo argument to `TruncDay`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/database-functions/#trunc):

> A **tzinfo** subclass, usually provided by **pytz**, can be passed to truncate a value in a specific timezone.

So: `.annotate(day=TruncDay('created', tzinfo=pytz.timezone('Pacific/Auckland')))`.